# Trying to install YouCompleteMe for vim

Tags: python, vim, plugins, anaconda, ubuntu-15.04

I was trying to install YCM for vim and I already have vundle installed. So I used :PluginInstall to install YCM. Now I am following this step.

Compiling YCM with semantic support for C-family languages:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.py --clang-completer
```

when i reach the directory and do the second command I get error:

```
Some folders in /home/shubham/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party are empty; you probably forgot to run:
    git submodule update --init --recursive


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./install.py", line 44, in <module>
    Main()
  File "./install.py", line 33, in Main
    subprocess.check_call( [ python_binary, build_file ] + sys.argv[1:] )
  File "/home/shubham/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/shubham/anaconda3/bin/python', '/home/shubham/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py', '--clang-completer']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

When I do python -V i get

```
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)
```

I installed YCM by adding

```
Plugin 'valloric/YouCompleteMe'
```

to the ~./.vimrc file

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 which by defalut had Python 2.7 and I explicitly installed anaconda3 and python3.

Please Help.

Comment: The YCM issue tracker is [this way](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you did this already as it was not listed in the question, but did you run `git submodule update --init --recursive`

```
Some folders in 
/home/shubham/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party 
are empty; you probably forgot to run:
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

If you have please update you question with the results and I will edit my answer, and see if we can get this figured out.